# How to write a Query annotation with collection parameter in Spring Data Elasticsearch repository

Tags: java, spring-data, spring-data-elasticsearch

In a `ProductRepository extends ElasticsearchRepository<Product, String>` I have a working query like:

```
@Query("{\"bool\": {"
        + "    \"filter\": ["
        + "        {\"term\": {\"CategoryID.keyword\": {\"value\": \"?0\"}}},"
        + "        {\"terms\": {\"Name.keyword\": [\"Name_A\",\"Name_B\",\"Name_C\"]}}"
        + "     ]"
        + "   }"
        + "}")
Stream<Product> findByCategoryIDAndNames(String categoryId, PageRequest pageRequest);
```

I need to have the `terms` values not hardcoded in the annotation but as `List<String>` argument to the method. I cannot find the correct way to write the Query annotation to query for a collection of names like:

```
@Query("{\"bool\": {"
        + "    \"filter\": ["
        + "        {\"term\": {\"CategoryID.keyword\": {\"value\": \"?0\"}}},"
        + "        {\"terms\": {\"Name.keyword\": [\"?1\"]}}"
        + "     ]"
        + "   }"
        + "}")
Stream<Product> findByCategoryIDAndNames(String categoryId, List<String> names, PageRequest pageRequest);
```

This compiles and runs without errors but doesn't work.
Looking in the [Spring Data Elasticsearch documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/current/reference/html/#elasticsearch.query-methods.at-query) I cannot find an example how to do this.

Spring Data Elasticsearch version: 4.0.4

Comment: I think you can make use of org.elasticsearch.index.query.BoolQueryBuilder and try instead of annotation, but needs custom implementation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Support for collection parameters was added with [PR #1856](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-elasticsearch/pull/1856) on July 3rd 2021 for the branches 4.3 to 4.1. The 4.0 branch has OSS support [until May 2021](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-commons/wiki/Release-Train-Neumann), so it is not updated anymore.

Comment: I'm stuck on a Fuse version for the moment. For now, I'll just have to use the template style. Thanks.